# Prove the equality of two ideals in $F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Prove $\langle x-1\rangle = I$ where $I= \{ a_0 x ^0 +\dots +a_n x^n: a_0+\dots +a_n=0\}$ in $F[x]$, $F$ a field.

---

**Proof**

we need to show $\langle x-1\rangle \subseteq I$ and $I \subseteq \langle x-1\rangle$

($\langle x-1\rangle \subseteq I$)

Let $f(x) \in \langle x-1\rangle$ so $\exists g(x) \in F[x]:f(x)=(x-1)g(x)$. Let $n-1= \deg g(x)$. So, 
$$f(x)=a_0x^0+\dots+a_nx^n=(x-1)g(x) $$
Let $x=1$, so $$f(1)=a_0(1)^0+\cdots +a_n (1)^n=a_0+\cdots +a_n=(1-1)g(x)=0.$$ 
So, $f(x) \in I$.

---

($I \subseteq \langle x-1\rangle$)

Now, Let $f(x) \in I \subset F[x]$
$$ f(x)=a_0x^0+\cdots +a_n x^n \text{ s.t. } a_0 +\cdots + a_n=0$$
We need

> **Remainder theorem** 
>   Let F be a field $f(x) \in F[x] $ and $a\in F$. The remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by the polynomial $x-a$ is f(a)

Note that $f(x)\in I \subset F[x]$, so $f(x) \in F[x]$ so we have also $1_F \in F[x]$ so dividing $f(x)$ by $(x-1)$ yields remainder $$f(1)=a_0+\cdots+a_n=0 $$
So, $x-1\mid f(x)\Leftrightarrow \exists g(x) \in F[x] \text{ s.t. } g(x)(x-1)=f(x)$
so $f(x) \in \langle x-1\rangle$

---

Making sure there are redundancy and I did not do something dumb. 
Did I make a mistake somewhere. Also, interested in other ways arriving to the same conclusion if possible and more elegant

Comment: Have you proven that polynomial rings over fields are PIDs? That proof can easily be adapted to this case.

Comment: @cuddlycuttlefish I have not proven polynomial rings over fields are PIDS. I am interested.

Comment: The proof boils down to showing that the (nonzero) element of smallest degree in the ideal is a generator for the ideal. Since $(x-1) \in I$, all you have to do is show that $I$ contains no nonzero constant elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks good to me.

Another proof goes as follows: Let $f:\Bbb{F}[x]\to \Bbb{F}:p \mapsto p(1)$. Then $\ker(f)=I$ by definition. Now, we also know that a polynomial has $1$ as a root if and only if it is divisible by $x-1$. So $\ker(f)=<x-1>$. Thus $I=<x-1>$.

Comment: Note: this proof implicitly uses the division algorithm.